# Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem error

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm currently running an optimization problem where I've simplified the code down to the following:

1 list of 90 numbers ranging from 0-100

1 list of 90 numbers that are binary

The ulitamte aim is to maxmize the dot product of these lists, subject to constraints (Only 2 for now, more will be added later)

Currently the 2 contraints are:

A binary check - to see if all numbers are 1 or 0

A total check - to make sure that the 2nd list sums to 15 (therefore the dot product is the sum of exactly 15 numbers from the first list)

When running the below code I'm seeing a "Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem" error.

I've tried running the same problem through excel solver and it's able to find the optimal solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize

Selected = (42.5,40.5,36.5,36.3,32.3,32.2,31,29.2,28.7,27.8,25.1,25,23.9,23.5,23.1,22.6,21.9,21.4,21.2,21,18.4,17.3,17,16.7,16.3,16.2,16.1,15.8,14.5,14,13.1,13,12.8,12.4,12,11.4,11.3,11,10.5,10.4,10.2,9.8,9.7,9.6,9.2,9.2,9.1,8.9,8.9,8.7,8.6,8.3,8,8,7.9,7.8,7.3,7.3,7.2,7.1,6.8,6.8,6.8,6.7,6.5,6.3,6.1,6,5.9,5.6,5.6,5.4,5.3,5.2,5.1,5.1,5,4.9,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.7,4.7,4.6,4.5,4.5,4.4,4.4,4.3,4.2)
Select = (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Select':Select,'Selected':Selected})


def MaxFunc(range):
    data_df['Select'] = range
    y = data_df[data_df['Select']==1]['Selected'].sum()
    return 1500 - y

def PCount(range):
    data_df['Select'] = range
    y = data_df[data_df['Select']==1]['Select'].count()
    return 15 - y

def BinCheck(range):
    Flag = 0
    for x in range:
        if (x != 0) & (x != 1):
            Flag = 1
    return Flag

con1={'type': 'eq','fun':PCount}
con2={'type': 'eq','fun':BinCheck}
constraints = [con1,con2]

Hedge = minimize(MaxFunc,Select,constraints=constraints)
```